# Remove WordPress auto cropping images completely

Tags: image, wordpress, crop

I am making a custom theme and have the site pretty much done. I am using types for custom fields that I use to upload images that are later put into a carousel. I am finding that when I upload an image 1069x1060 it is not cropped or touched and the whole content of the image is visible. Now When I upload a picture 850x700 the image gets cropped and the whole area is not visible

this can be seen at http://blog.jmrowe.com/portfolio  just look for the rotating pictures and you'll notice one is cropped and unable to see the whole content.

Also, I unchecked the option "Crop thumbnail to exact dimensions (normally thumbnails are proportional)" under settings -> media and this did not help. I did not add any custom feature image sizes.

What's weird is that when I select the image it shows in the tiny preview screen the image un-cropped. However, when the site is actually visited the image is cropped. I also selected use "Full size"

Can someone please help?

I am using types custom fields plugin to actually show these in the theme like:

```
<?php if (!((get_post_meta($post->ID, 'wpcf-portfoliopicture1', TRUE))=='')): ?>
<div class="row">
                        <div class="span8">
             <div class="span6 offset1" style="padding-left:20px;">
             <?php
$param['height']=350;
$param['width']=325; 
$param['alt']=types_render_field("portfoliotitle1",$param2);
$param['title']=types_render_field("portfoliotitle1",$param2);
?>
<ul class="round">
<li><?php echo(types_render_field("portfoliopicture1", $param)); ?></li>
<?php
$param['alt']=types_render_field("portfoliotitle2",$param2);
$param['title']=types_render_field("portfoliotitle2",$param2);
 ?>
<li><?php echo(types_render_field("portfoliopicture2", $param)); ?></li>
<?php
$param['alt']=types_render_field("portfoliotitle3",$param2);
$param['title']=types_render_field("portfoliotitle3",$param2);
 ?>
<li><?php echo(types_render_field("portfoliopicture3", $param)); ?></li>
</ul>
</div>



                        </div>
                    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I notice if I go into wp-includes/media.php and goto function image_resize_dimensions

that I can edit out some of the function and it won't auto-crop the images..however, it will not resize them either so a picture natively 1000px x 900px will be just that

I AM Pretty sure that the problem lies in the wp-includes\media.php function below:

```
function image_resize_dimensions($orig_w, $orig_h, $dest_w, $dest_h, $crop = false) {


    if ($orig_w <= 0 || $orig_h <= 0)
        return false;
    // at least one of dest_w or dest_h must be specific
    if ($dest_w <= 0 && $dest_h <= 0)
        return false;

    // plugins can use this to provide custom resize dimensions
    $output = apply_filters( 'image_resize_dimensions', null, $orig_w, $orig_h, $dest_w, $dest_h, $crop );
    if ( null !== $output )
        return $output;

    if ( $crop ) { 

        // crop the largest possible portion of the original image that we can size to $dest_w x $dest_h
        $aspect_ratio = $orig_w / $orig_h;
        $new_w = min($dest_w, $orig_w);
        $new_h = min($dest_h, $orig_h);

        if ( !$new_w ) {
            $new_w = intval($new_h * $aspect_ratio);
        }

        if ( !$new_h ) {
            $new_h = intval($new_w / $aspect_ratio);
        }

        $size_ratio = max($new_w / $orig_w, $new_h / $orig_h);

        $crop_w = round($new_w / $size_ratio);
        $crop_h = round($new_h / $size_ratio);

        $s_x = floor( ($orig_w - $crop_w) / 2 );
        $s_y = floor( ($orig_h - $crop_h) / 2 );
    } else {
        // don't crop, just resize using $dest_w x $dest_h as a maximum bounding box
        $crop_w = $orig_w;
        $crop_h = $orig_h;

        $s_x = 0;
        $s_y = 0;

        list( $new_w, $new_h ) = wp_constrain_dimensions( $orig_w, $orig_h, $dest_w, $dest_h );
    }

    // if the resulting image would be the same size or larger we don't want to resize it
    if ( $new_w >= $orig_w && $new_h >= $orig_h )
        return false;

    // the return array matches the parameters to imagecopyresampled()
    // int dst_x, int dst_y, int src_x, int src_y, int dst_w, int dst_h, int src_w, int src_h
    return array( 0, 0, (int) $s_x, (int) $s_y, (int) $new_w, (int) $new_h, (int) $crop_w, (int) $crop_h );

}
```

I know I shouldn't mess with the core files but when I do it effects my problem but I can not figure out what will fix it. This function is called by the plugin ( types - custom types and fields ) and this is where the cropping is happening

Comment: I notice the cropping only happens when the image is under about 1000px in length.. any ideas how I can prevent the cropping at all?

Comment: Where is the code that displays those images? Which WP function are you using to display them?

Comment: @BenRacicot I edited post to show

Comment: It looks like you're displaying the images with types_render_field. I don't know that plugin but accessing the custom fields value using get_post_custom function has solved issues for others. Then echoing the native get_the_post_thumbnail($id, $size, $attr ) with the desired sizes will ensure proper image size. Sorry I can't help more.

Comment: I don't see how if I use get_post_custom to get the img url that it will work for get_the_post_thumbnail? Won't get_the_post_thumbnail return 1 item? There are 3 in this instance. Thanks for your help either way

Comment: The reason I recommended that is because via a Google search I saw that other people have had your type of issue and swapped the functions to grab their meta-data. I think your issue is with the plugin's retrieval method more so than the output. But you would be a better judge of that.

Comment: @BenRacicot I eddited my post.. your right, I'm pretty sure it is happening during a filter when the plugin retrieves the image. The function I posted about is what is causing the cropping

Comment: You were uploading images and getting the sizes you wanted for two images and one image was being sized wrong correct? I would not mess with core but try to customize the plugin. Have you looked into disabling image resizing?

Answer (score 0):

I just dl'ed and ran through the files. From what you say it is clearly grabbing one wrong image size despite the correct code (confirmed with the instructions at includes/fields/image.php)

You could play around with customizing the plugin a bit. I've found [wp_handle_upload](http://bit.ly/f5CEvf) to override the upload process.

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'wp_handle_upload' ) ) require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php' );
$uploadedfile = $_FILES['file'];
$upload_overrides = array( 'test_form' => false );
$movefile = wp_handle_upload( $uploadedfile, $upload_overrides );
if ( $movefile ) {
    echo "File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.\n";
    var_dump( $movefile);
} else {
    echo "Possible file upload attack!\n";
}
```

Other than this I would have to speak with the dev about your issue. I can't find anything else to help without being logged into your site. :) Hope you the best, I'll be watching this page.

Comment: I ended up editing the types plugin where the image_resize_dimensions is called from the plugin and manually setting $crop to false. It stopped the cropping of images but now I'm dealing with properly re sizing the image. I should of just used laravel instead of wordpress but oh well

Comment: Ugh yeah sorry. Can you photoshop edit them to the right size pre-upload so you get consistent results? Never used Laravel

Comment: Yeah that is what I'm doing. Not as precise as I'd hope but I guess this is one of the pitfalls of wordpress.. thanks for your help @BenRacicot